# Pyinstaller and keeping .py

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am new to programming, discovered pyinstaller and really need to know: do I need to keep .py file or is it ok to delete the .py and .spec files from dir.

I use pyinstaller -w -F [file.py]

Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you delete it? ;)

Comment: It wasn't ironic. It is easier to try than to ask. It is better to try than to ask. If I was going to answer you, I'd first try to make sure my answer was right. So why don't you just try?

Comment: oky I mean it works but I plan on putting it on another pc and I want to make sure xd